# Periodic boundary conditions or spherical potential?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, intermolecular-forces, qmmm, periodic-boundary-conditions

I was wondering whether you know if there is any sort of literature discussing whether periodic boundary conditions or spherical potentials could be better or worse for QM/MM or MM simulations, their impact in the dynamics... Any sort of material is welcome. What would you choose?

I know periodic boundary conditions are more broadly used but I want to know the pros of the spherical potentials too.

Thank you!

Comment: PBC avoids the issue of surface tension, which can be quite large on the small systems often simulated atomistically, but, perhaps you are interested in the surface tension of a droplet? Perhaps you are interested in droplets in general.

PBC is necessary for Bulk property estimation

Comment: I don't understand why you consider periodic boundary conditions incompatible with spherical potentials. Do you simply mean PBC vs vacuum boundaries?

Comment: This post appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP addresses questions/suggestions from the comments.